# RC4 and Crypto Ransomware

Tags: patching, ransomware

If we allow no RC4 support on any devices, will Crypto Ransomware be slowed down or eliminated?

Is this a patching and not a malware problem? Can we block this threat at the packet level?

Comment: What on earth does RC4 have to do with ransomware? And how, exactly, do you prevent software from implementing the RC4 algorithm?

Comment: Weak encryption implementations (SSL) allow hosts to talk to TOR based C&C hosts. You didn't know that? :)

Comment: First, I'll need to see a source on why ransomware needs a weak stream cipher, and why it couldn't simply use AES or any other TLS suite. Second, you can't stop software from implementing something unless you've found that software and are in the process of modifying it. But you don't patch malware. You _remove_ it. (patching is not new to me; it's that you can't patch something unless you know it's there, but the whole point of malware is you don't know it's there until it's too late)

Comment: Cpast is asking all the right questions. Don't dismiss him so quickly. Your question is confusing with underlying assumptions that need investigation. Doesn't Cryptowall use RSA encryption? If your sole point is that RC4 is used to connect to C&C servers, Cryptowall can use Dropbox, Google Drive, and even local files or network shares. RC4 simply isn't necessary to connect to C&C. Can you provide your reasons for why you think weak SSL is required?

Comment: @GreggDotoli, please take your own advice and remember to remain civil. Even if someone is asking you incredulous questions, he is still trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You have two main misconceptions: one, just because a number of publicized ransomware programs use RC4, it doesn't mean they *have* to, or that they couldn't just switch to AES for newer versions; two, patches *cannot* prevent an algorithm from being used on a computer (patches affect the behavior of a single piece of software, but can't generally cover everything using an algorithm).

Stopping RC4 from being used will not in any way prevent ransomware from working (at most, it'll make certain currently existing programs not work, but it's simple enough to fix them to still work with AES instead of RC4. There is no situation in which ransomware *relies* on RC4; AES is a superior alternative, and the ones that use RC4 started because it was thought to be secure enough and continue because it still works fine for them. It would interrupt some ransomware for a bit, but would very quickly become a useless change. There are two cases where RC4 works where AES isn't a valid substitute: if you want the message to be decrypted by someone without the key (that actually can be the case, so an attacker thinks they've decrypted a secret communication when you really meant them to decrypt it), or if you have to support a legacy system requiring it. Ransomware doesn't have any use for the former, and doesn't need the latter (C&C networks might have to be changed a bit, but that's not actually that hard).

Secondly, there is no way to prevent RC4 from being used, with patching or otherwise. A ransomware program using RC4 could use system libraries (which could be patched to remove RC4 support), but it could just as easily implement it itself, or copy an open-source implementation (even if the open-source library is changed to remove support, they could copy the old version). It's impossible to automatically detect code to implement RC4 and block that; the only way to stop it is to look at the specific malware, find where it's using RC4, and change the code to stop it. But unless you're a security researcher, you don't patch malware; you remove the malware outright. So, you aren't patching the ransomware client. You can't patch the server, as you don't control it. You're left intercepting it at the network level. TLS will say in the handshake what cipher suite it's using, but in general there's no good way to tell RC4 ciphertext from AES ciphertext from random data. So you can't stop RC4 packets unless they use TLS, but as mentioned above, that really has little effect on ransomware.

Comment: To add, RC4 is stupid easy to implement.  So to your second point, it's not only possible for malware to embed an internal implementation, it might actually be harder to find and rely on external implementations.

Comment: If we force all client traffic  thru a proxy that only supports Tls 1.x, then unpatched ssl based communications will fail. By policy , we will reduce risk.

Comment: Can anyone refer me to a good resource for managing RansomwareCrypto in the enterprise? Maybe a Best Practice checklist. ***Thank you in advance!***

Comment: If you blocked SSL 3.0, a particular implementation of ransomware that required SSL 3.0 would be unable to contact its C&C to save the encryption key. But it most likely would still have encrypted the files by that point. So you'd have prevented it from threatening to destroy all your files, but only by pre-emptively destroying all your files. Not a big win! But the point is moot as currently prevalent strains of ransomware do not rely on SSL 3.0 or RC4 in general.